# Just a little recursion issue in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm currently just working my way through some recursion problems, and I am currently stuck on one.

The problem is to recursively insert spaces into a string, into every single possible location, such that the output looks something like:

```
Input: ABCD
Out:
       ABCD
       A BCD
       A B CD
       A B C D
       A BC D
       AB CD
       AB C D
       ABC D
```

I have currently worked on the problem, and got to a point much like:

```
Input: ABCD
Out:
       ABCD
       A BCD
       A B CD
       A B C D
```

My code for the problem so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Words 
{
    static int counter = 0;
    static String fString = "";
    static String fString2 = "";
    static String previous = "";
    static String input = "";
    static String other = "";

    public static String segment(String inputPrefix, String restOfString)
{
    if(restOfString.length() != 0)
    {   
        if(inputPrefix.equals(""))
        {
            fString += restOfString + "\n";
            segment(restOfString.substring(0,1), restOfString.substring(1));
        }
        else
        {
            previous += inputPrefix + " ";
            fString += previous + restOfString + "\n";
            fString2 = previous + restOfString;
            segment(restOfString.substring(0,1)
                            , restOfString.substring(1));
        }
    }
    /*else
    {
        counter++;
        other = fString2.replaceAll(" ", "");
        System.out.println(other);
        if((counter + 1) < other.length())
        {
            System.out.println("Other: " + other);
            input = other.substring(0, counter + 1);
            other = other.substring(counter + 1);
            System.out.println(counter);
            System.out.println("input: " + input);
            System.out.print("other: " + other);

            segment(input, other);
        }
        else
            return fString;
    }*/

    return fString;

}

public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String input = scan.next();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(segment("", input));

}
}
```

That second else clause is where I am having my most trouble, because every time I run it un-commented it goes into an infinite loop. I even put int trace statements (the `println` statements) and it still isn't helping.

I've read through it many times and it just doesn't make sense to me why it doesn't work.

Comment: +1 great example of a homework question. Shows the code so far and exactly which part of the question is the problem.

Comment: When I want a recursive solution, it helps me to think 'what a program has to do' and not 'how a program will do it'.

Comment: +1 been looking around for a decent programmatic brain exercise!

Comment: The way the output strings are listed can give you a hint on how to recurse

Comment: I second the point made by Soronthar. It is intuitive up to A B C D but what is the logic after that? I know it is hard to explain in words for people that did not get it (me) :)

Comment: I think he wants a solution written in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've been able to do the first 'grouping' correctly, but unable to get the next groupings.

The groupings are: 'A BCD', 'AB CD', and 'ABC D'. You need to apply your algorithm to each of these groupings. You've applied it to the first. How do you get the rest of them?

Has enough time passed? I wrote up a python solution just to see what it'd look like compared to Java.

```python
def segment(input, separator=' ', start_from=0):
    print input
    # add spaces after each letter starting from start_from index, terminating at last letter-1
    for i in range(start_from, len(input)-1):
        # if the next letter is already a space, or this letter is a space, move on
        if separator in (input[i+1], input[i]): continue
        # whatever index we're on, do the next one recursively
        segment(input[:i] + input[i] + separator + input[i+1:], separator=separator, start_from=i+1)

segment('ABCD')
```

Comment: What if I want to put more than one space? for example if I get ABCD I could put A  BCD (2 spaces)

Comment: @Dejel notice the `separator` argument? Just make that two spaces instead of one. ie: `segment('ABCD', separator='  ')`.

Comment: I meant play around - one time to put one space and at the other time to put the separator as 2 spaces

Comment: @Dejel You'd need some logic inside the `for` loop that changes what the separator is going to be for the next recursive step.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that makes me dubious about your code is that you are supposed to returning a series of strings, but your return value is a string.

Perhaps, you should nail down your base case and recursive step.

It looks like you've got a start on the base case.  You can insert zero spaces in the empty string, so

```
allPossibleSpacings("") -> [ "" ]
```

but you don't want to insert a space at the end, so you need a second base case

```
allPossibleSpacings("x") -> [ "x" ]
```

and then your recursive step could be

```
allPossibleSpacings("x" + s) -> flatten(
    ∀ t : allPossibleSpacings(s), ["x" + t, "x " + t])
```

I won't help you write that in Java since it's homework, but hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't know the ∀ symbol existed without using something like TeX...awesome!

Comment: @Michael McGowan, unicode page 22xx has all kinds of handy math symbols.  http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf

Comment: What's this notation language called ?

Comment: @hini Which notation?  I'm mixing different notations, so it's kind of pseudocodish.   The "->" means [reduces to](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs430/lectureNotes/terse/Smallstep.html) but I should probably use a fat arrow.  "∀" is the [universal quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification).  Then I'm using square brackets to delimit arrays which is not very Java-esque.

Answer (score 3):

```
void recurse(String myString, int start){
        System.out.println(myString);
        for(int i = start; i < myString.length; i++) {
            if (myString.charAt(i) != ' ' ){
                recurse(myString.Substring(0,i) + ' ' + myString.Substring(i), i+2);
            }
        }
    }
```

call first with recurse("ABCD", 1);

Comment: -0.5 The point of homework is to learn to think about a problem, not to have an answer provided for you.

Comment: I just like solving things like this :(

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin What if I need to do something different, I get an unknown length of string and need to insert spaces up to string being with length of 6. For instance if I get ABCD I could insert A  BCD (2 spaces after the A) or A BCD (1 space after the A)

Comment: @Dejel, ask it as a question, it's too long to reply with a comment